# NX cli command not working correctly on my workspace based angular

Tags: angular, typescript, graph, nrwl-nx, nx-workspace

I am creating an nx workspace based on Angular, everything is working fine and I have installed nx globally.
when launching the nx dep-graph command, the editor displays the window how do you want to open this window.

even if I launch the nx command alone the same window is displayed,
where is the problem, and why the graph does not launch on the port: 4211 automatically.

package.json

```
  "name": "my-project2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main",
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.2.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "14.7.5",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.2.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.7.5",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.7.5",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.7.5",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.7.5",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.7.5",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.7.5",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.1",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "cypress": "^10.7.0",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "~12.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "~14.2.0",
    "nx": "^14.7.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-import": "~14.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "~7.5.0",
    "postcss-url": "~10.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsdNQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can run `nx graph` to open the dependency graph at a url like http://127.0.0.0:4211/projects.

In your case, Windows is asking which application should be used to open it. You can select Google Chrome and tick the box to make it default.
the next time you run `nx graph`, it should open on Chrome at the specified address by default.